# TypeError: a float is required and ending statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot figure out what I need to do. Can someone please help me?

```
import math


def main():
phrases = " Pythagorean Theorem a b c"       # String literal

print("Welcome to the "+phrases[1:13]+"Problem Solver")
print("This solves the problem of only knowing two sides of right triangle, and solves for the one you don't know")
question = input('Do you know two variables in the theorem?: ')
if question == 'yes':
    variables = input('What variables do you know? ab, ac, bc')
if variables == 'ab':
    a1 = input('What is the Value of a?:')
    b1 = input('What is the Value of b?:')
    c1 = math.sqrt(a1+b1)
    print(c1)
if variables == 'ac':
    a2 = input('What is the Value of a? :')
    c2 = input('What is the Value of c? :')
    b2 = math.sqrt(a2+c2)
    print(b2)
if variables == 'bc':
    b3 = input('What is the Value of b? :')
    c3 = input('What is the Value of c? :')
    a3 = math.sqrt(b3+c3)
    print(a3)
main()
```

I'm getting this as an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/RobotAdmin/PycharmProjects/Class/pythagoreantsolver.py", line     33, in <module>
    main()

File "C:/Users/RobotAdmin/PycharmProjects/Class/pythagoreantsolver.py", line     21,       in main
    c1 = math.sqrt(a1+b1)
TypeError: a float is required
```

Could anyone please tell me what I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

The operation `math.sqrt` requires numeric types. However when you accept values using `input` they are of type `str`. You need to convert them from `str` to `float`

```
a1 = float(input('What is the Value of a?:'))
b1 = float(input('What is the Value of b?:'))
c1 = math.sqrt(a1+b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, above main, you have a variable called `question`. It is not defined. This is because you did not *return* a variable inside your `main()`. So we should put `return question` at the end of the def. like so:

```
def main():
    phrases = " Pythagorean Theorem a b c"       # String literal
    print("Welcome to the "+phrases[1:13]+"Problem Solver")
    print("This solves the problem of only knowing two sides of right triangle, and solves for the one you don't know")
    question = input('Do you know two variables in the theorem?: ')
    return question ####<------THIS THIS THIS############
```

Then, below that line, write `question = main()` (not indented). This would run `main()`, take the answer to the question that you returned, and store it to the variable `question` in your non-indented code.

like so:

```
def main():
    phrases = " Pythagorean Theorem a b c"       # String literal
    print("Welcome to the "+phrases[1:13]+"Problem Solver")
    print("This solves the problem of only knowing two sides of right triangle, and solves for the one you don't know")
    question = input('Do you know two variables in the theorem?: ')
    return question

##HEY LOOK AT THIS##
question = main()
```

After all this, notice that a1, b1, a2, c2, b3, and c3 would all be STRINGS with the `input()` function. Just put a `float()` around that and you'll be fine.

```
if variables == 'ab':
    a1 = float(input('What is the Value of a?:')) #LOOK FLOATY FLOAT#
    b1 = float(input('What is the Value of b?:'))
    c1 = math.sqrt(a1+b1)
    print(c1)
```

That'll make it work.